# Technical detail regarding suspending and resuming a running thread

Tags: java

I have a class which use to perform currency exchange monitoring activities, and it is having ability to suspend and resume. I have the following questions regarding my class design.

1. Is it necessary to have `has_started` as volatile?
2. Is it necessary to have `suspend` as volatile? I had seen the example from [Exampledepot](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/PauseThread.html), the flag is not marked as volatile.
3. When I catch `InterruptedException` during `wait`, shall I `return`, or shall I just ignore the exception?

Also, I am getting NetBeans warning on having multiple `synchronized` block. Is it a valid warning?

```
public synchronized void suspend() {
    synchronized(currencyExchangeRunnable) {
        suspend = true;
    }
}
```

My first level synchronized are use to prevent multiple threads from executing suspend/resume/start/stop. And my second level of synchronized block, is to pair with `wait/notify`

My initial testing on suspend/resume/start/stop is that, they work as expected. However, I am not sure is there any other catches behind?

---

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

/**
 *
 * @author yccheok
 */
public class CurrencyExchangeMonitor {

    /**
     * Starts currency exchange monitoring activities. This method can be called
     * multiple times. start/stop/suspend/resume are being synchronized with
     * each others.
     */
    public synchronized void start() {
        if (has_started) {
            return;
        }
        executor.submit(currencyExchangeRunnable);
        has_started = true;
    }

    /**
     * Stop all currency exchange monitoring activities. Once it is stopped, it
     * cannot be started again. This method will only return once it is being
     * terminated completely. start/stop/suspend/resume are being synchronized
     * with each others.
     */
    public synchronized void stop() {
        executor.shutdownNow();
        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(100, TimeUnit.DAYS);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            log.error(null, ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Temporary suspend all ongoing monitoring activities. This method can be
     * called multiple times. start/stop/suspend/resume are being synchronized
     * with each others.
     */
    public synchronized void suspend() {
        synchronized(currencyExchangeRunnable) {
            suspend = true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Resume all ongoing monitoring activities. This method can be called
     * multiple times. start/stop/suspend/resume are being synchronized with
     * each others.
     */
    public synchronized void resume() {
        synchronized(currencyExchangeRunnable) {
            suspend = false;
            currencyExchangeRunnable.notify();
        }
    }

    private class CurrencyExchangeRunnable implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!executor.isShutdown()) {
                synchronized(this) {
                    while (suspend) {
                        try {
                            wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            log.error(null, ex);
                            // Usually triggered by executor.shutdownNow
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private volatile boolean suspend = false;
    private volatile boolean has_started = false;
    private final CurrencyExchangeRunnable currencyExchangeRunnable = new CurrencyExchangeRunnable();
    private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(CurrencyExchangeMonitor.class);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1,2) Since both variables are accessed only in synchronized blocks, they need not be volatile.

(3) It's usually best to do something with InterruptedException.  If, however, you control all the code in the process and you never interrupt threads it can be ignored.

Nested synchronized blocks can lead to deadlocks if the code isn't written carefully.  You must always (all code paths) acquire the locks in the same order.

I agree with juskt on "Java Concurrency in Practice".  It's a very good book.

Comment: The question is, is the above multiple synchronized able to cause any potential deadlock?

Comment: @Yan - Darron answers your question pretty well - always acquire locks in the same order to avoid deadlock.

Comment: @justkt, I know what Darron means. But he just didn't mention whether there is a possibility for my code to acquire lock in wrong order. My thought is that, since CurrencyExchangeRunnable will never call CurrencyExchangeMonitor's stop, so deadlock shall not happen. I am not sure whether my thought is correct.

Comment: I think your existing code is okay at this time.  But learning the rule is important for future code.

Answer (score 1):

1. Since multiple threads my change `has_started`, you would usually mark it as `volatile`.  Since it is accessed only within a synchronized block, you need not do this
2. Since multiple threads may change `suspend`, you would usually mark it as `volatile`.  Since it is accessed only within a synchronized block, you need not do this
3. It is a good practice to always do something with `InterruptedException`.  `InterruptedException` means your wait has been interrupted by some other thread - perhaps a shut down thread from a browser plug-in (for an applet) or an application server (in JavaEE).  When you catch interrupted exception, the recommended thing to do is call `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` to handle it.  That is what your executor will be expecting.

The excellent book [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/) would be just what you need to dig into the details on concurrency.

Comment: The question is, is the above multiple synchronized able to cause any potential deadlock?